# How to provide a citation call-out in a definition?

Tags: theorems

i have used following

```
\documentclass{report}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[chapter]
\begin{document}
\begin{df}
\cite{wilson} The join of two function...
\end{df}
\end{document}
```

and the output is

> **Definition 1.1.** [5] *The join of two functions...*

but I am in need of the output

> **Definition 1.1** [5]. *The join of two...*

I need a full stop (period) after "[5]".

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you load the `amsthm` package and set up a new "theorem style" along the lines provided on page 10 of the user guide of the package's user guide. Then, place the citation command in the optional argument of the `\begin{df}[...]` instruction.

[image]

The reason "?" is shown in the screenshot instead of, say, "5" is that I don't have access to the "wilson" bib entry. If you want the citation number to be bold as well, remove the `\mdseries` instruction in the setup of the `noparens` theorem style.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{noparens}% % see p. 10 of user guide of amsthm package
{}{}%
{\itshape}{}%
{\bfseries}{.}%
{ }%
{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}\mdseries\thmnote{ #3}}
\theoremstyle{noparens}
\newtheorem{df}{Definition}[chapter]

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % just for this example
\begin{df}[\cite{wilson}]
The join of two functions...
\end{df}
\end{document}
```